# Javascript Iteration issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate over the following Code and for some reason each time i iterate over it, it fires off the event handler, does any one know why it would be automatically firing off the handler?

```
nmbr = 1;           
 x1 =   document.getElementsByClassName('fp')[0]  ;  
        slowSkrol = document.createElement('button'); 
        slowSkrol.className = 'mods'; 
        slowSkrol.value= nmbr; 
            x1.appendChild(slowSkrol);  
        slowSkrol.addEventListener('click', whenclicked(nmbr),false);
function whenclicked(vv){
alert(vv);
}
```

Comment: Notice how [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/VzgUe/), but [this doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/VzgUe/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function, and binding it's return value to the event, rather than binding the function itself to the event. Replace `whenclicked(nmbr)` with:

```
function(){ whenclicked(nmbr); }
```

In modern browsers you could also use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
whenclicked.bind(null, nmbr);
```

Comment: Alternatively (where bind is available): `slowSkrol.addEventListener('click', whenclick.bind(slowSkrol, nmbr))`. That does over-force the `this` assigned via the event, though ..

Comment: @user2246674 and therefore be a bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
slowSkrol.addEventListener('click', whenclicked(nmbr),false);
```

to

```
slowSkrol.addEventListener('click', function() {
    whenclicked(nmbr); 
},false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't be adding another answer really. but the correct way to do this so that you get all arguments and the `this` would be like so.

```
slowSkrol.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
   whenclicked.apply(this, [event, nmbr]);
}, false);
```

Then you can use it like so.

```
function whenclicked( event, nmbr ){
   alert(this, event, nmbr);
   // this = slowSkrol
}
```